# Putting a RC filter after the photo-diode to AC-couple the TIA gain stage

Tags: photodiode, transimpedance, transimpedance-amplifier

I have been designing a photo-diode circuit which separates out DC and AC signal of the photodiode. I am using MAX4007 as the current mirror for the DC branch and I am using OPA858 as the Transimpedance amplifier.

However, due to the limited dynamic range of opa858, 2.5Vpp output swing, I am level shifting the TIA and AC couple the TIA. This creates a current division of the current comimg out of the photodiode between R8 and R1. Will this create any problem? [image]

I wonder what is causing the 1.1V voltage drop of MAX4007 between the BIAS pin and the REF pin?

I have attached my circuit below and if you find any problems or concerns in this circuit design, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The 1.1V drop is related to the design of the MAX4007. Although 1.1V is right at the data sheet maximum

[image]

[Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4007-MAX4008.pdf)

There isn't an internal circuit provided but it may have a current mirror or probably in this case it uses a amplifier with feedback.